# inequality on minimum singular values of matrices A, B, and A+B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw an inequality on minimum singular values of matrices A, B, and A+B.

σmin(A)+σmin(B)≥σmin(A+B)

I want to know how can it be proven (if it is true) or what is the correct inequality on σmin(A+B) (if it is not true)

Comment: If you were to take the elements of $\textbf A$ and $\textbf B$ and make them sets $A$ and $B$, respectively, and define $f:A\times B\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a,b)=a+b$, what is the minimum value in the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. For a counterexample, consider the case where $A$ and $B$ are singular (so that their minimum singular values are zero) but $A+B$ is invertible (so that its minimum singular value is positive), e.g. when $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$ and $B$ is the all-one matrix.

To obtain an upper bound for $\sigma_\min(A+B)$, you may use Weyl's inequality
$$
\sigma_{i+j-1}(A+B)\le\sigma_i(A)+\sigma_j(B),
$$
which holds whenever $i+j-1$ does not exceed the minimum dimension of $A$. In particular,
$$
\sigma_\min(A+B)\le\min\left\{\sigma_\min(A)+\sigma_\max(B),\ \sigma_\max(A)+\sigma_\min(B)\right\}.
$$